# FBSDK for iOS: "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

After integrating the Facebook SDK i get the following error immediatly after launch of the app:
"unrecognized selector sent to instance"

*What i did:*

I setup a plain simple view controller app with XCode 6 for iOS 8.2 and integrated the Facebook iOS SDK with Cocoapods.

I worked thru the "Getting Started" Section and put the nesseccary code into AppDelegate and changed the .plist-File.
When running the application, it stops immediatly with a "unrecognized selector"-Error.

I also tried out the Example-App "Scrumptious" from the Facebook-SDK, which runs very fine. I build the code from Scrumptions into my app, and stuck on the same error as before. Below i will post the callstack.

Facebook recommends the -ObjC Switch into the linker flags to solve those errors. But this Flag is already set (i think cocoapods did that already).

What can i do? What is missing?

This is the callstack:

```
2015-04-09 15:58:40.949 myapp[65629:2910713] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbd6b741140'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103205a75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102e9ebb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010320cd1d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001031649dc ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103164578 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   myapp                             0x0000000100993c66 __107+[FBSDKAppEventsUtility activityParametersDictionaryForEvent:implicitEventsOnly:shouldAccessAdvertisingID:]_block_invoke + 470
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104257614 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104243881 dispatch_once_f + 565
    8   myapp                             0x000000010099388a +[FBSDKAppEventsUtility activityParametersDictionaryForEvent:implicitEventsOnly:shouldAccessAdvertisingID:] + 1114
    9   myapp                             0x000000010099be4c +[FBSDKAppLinkUtility fetchDeferredAppLink:] + 780
    10  myapp                             0x0000000100974e6e -[AppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:] + 142
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000101bd3f96 -[UIApplication _stopDeactivatingForReason:] + 313
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000101be8ea2 -[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:] + 2648
    13  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000105b33243 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010313ac7c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001031309c5 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103130785 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010312fbc6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000103b72a58 GSEventRunModal + 161
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000101bd9580 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    20  myapp                             0x00000001009753b3 main + 115
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010428c145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at your plist-File. It must contain the FacebookAppId, the DisplayName and the URL Schemes. If only one is missing, you'll get such an error.

Here is one of my apps which are working correctly with the Facebook-API:
[image: Plist-File]

Comment: Thank you very much! I passed the AppID into the first item under URL Types without the second Node "URL Schemes". That caused this error.